# iOS 9 / 10 NavigationController Difference

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Swift application that is displaying a MainViewController (Root View Controller). In my MainView i have a UIView lets call it MenuView that is placed outside the screen on the left. MenuView is holding a TableViewController.
The MenuView can be viewed by coming in from left if you click the menu button.
In this MenuView you will have cells that are clickable and if you click the cells I will push a new ViewController of another type on top.
This means that I will have another view stacked on top of my rootviewcontroller on the navigation stack.
Now to the problem:

On iOS 10 units if you click the menu that is visible after clicking menu button another view is presented as expected. If u then click the back button you will be coming back to the MainViewController and the MenuView is still placed on the screen just as last state.

On iOS 9 the MenuView is now moved to its original position outside the screen to the left.

Anyone have any idea what this can be ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, my problem was that I had a constraint that was reseting the position of my view everytime that the view were redrawn and the difference of the iOS 9 and 10 was that it seems that iOS 9 were redrawing it more often